# Export from SQL Server 2012 to .CSV through Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 database that I am trying to export to `.CSV`. My knowledge of SQL is very basic and my question is, I'm assuming it would be done in Management Studio, how do I do this?

Answer (score 59):

If it is the query results you want exported to csv, you can right click on the results grid and select "Save Results As", which will allow you to save as csv.

Comment: how would you export dates?

Comment: This does not save the headers

Comment: No, but you can do a "Select All" on the grid, then right click, and select "Copy with Headers" (or press Ctrl+Shift+C). You can then paste into excel, or wherever you like.

Comment: In Sql Server Management Studio 2012 "Save Results As" included the headers for me. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: To get the headers, go to the Query menu; select Query Options; navigate to Results > Grid and select "Include column headers when copying or saving the results"

Comment: Those previous instructions are **per-query.** To set this as the **default**, go to the Tools menu; select Options; navigate to Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid and select "Include column headers when copying or saving the results".

Answer (score 42):

Right click on your database in management studio and choose **`Tasks` -> `Export Data...`**

Follow a wizard, and in destination part choose **'Flat File Destination'**. Type your file name and choose your options.

Comment: Thanks, I cant get the wizard to complete though. It gets through the first step, I select flat file and choose .csv format, then it returns this error: "Columns are not defined for this connection manager."

Comment: @WebblyBrown Are you sure you have selected source and destination correctly? This sounds like an error that you are choosing flat file as source rather then destination. First step in wizard is source, don't touch it, it should be DB where you clicked On 2nd step choose flat file as destination.

Comment: Ok one last question I hope, how do I get it to select all the tables? The wizard takes me to a place where is says copy from one or more tables, however the next screen I cant work out how to select multiple or select all tables, right now its just exports tables one by one to csv...

Comment: If anyone else is having trouble, take a look at [this](http://blog.winhost.com/exporting-sql-server-data-with-import-and-export-wizard/) for full tutorial

Comment: This approach does not work if you are connecting to an Azure SQL Database.  In that case, the "Save Results As" solution from Nick Howard is better.