# How to export selective columns of multiple tables from SQL Server to one csv file?

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv

In SQL Server (or SQL Server Data Tools) is there a way to export selective columns of multiple tables from SQL Server to one csv file?
The database is a Linked Server object connected in SQL Server connected ODBC.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471994/export-from-sql-server-2012-to-csv-through-management-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do for a onetime deal: Copy-paste in Excel, and save that file in CSV.